# JSON string getting escaped

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am sending a string from JSON ASP.NET MVC, in my view I receive the JSON string and I assign a Script using ViewBag.string. 
My problem is in the view, the string type values ​​are replacing the quotes with me & quot; which is causing me errors.

Controller:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string retorno = jss.Serialize(chart.ToList());
ViewBag.datos = retorno;
```

ViewL

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Morris.Bar({
        element: 'BarChart',
        data:@ViewBag.datos,
        xkey: 'Planta',
        ykeys: 'Cantidad',
        labels: 'Mes'
    })
</script>
```

This is the code that generates me to run the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Morris.Bar({
        element: 'BarChart',
        data:`[{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;CO&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:3,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:2},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;EP&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:1,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:1},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;R1&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:1,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:2},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;RM&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:3,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:3},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;RQ&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:3,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:1},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;TY&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:1,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:1},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;TY&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:3,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:3},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;TY&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:4,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:2},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;ZB&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:3,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:1},{&quot;Planta&quot;:&quot;ZB&quot;,&quot;Mes&quot;:4,&quot;Cantidad&quot;:1}],`
        xkey: 'Planta',
        ykeys: 'Cantidad',
        labels: 'Mes'
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried JSON.NET instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor is assuming the content is HTML and is escaping your JSON. Use `Html.Raw` to stop this behaviour.

```
...
data:@Html.Raw(ViewBag.datos)
...
```